# How right to send Flux or Mono to template (Freemaker)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, freemarker

I got from my repository Flux and in my controller I want to send it to my template.
my controller:

```
 @GetMapping("users")
    public String getAllUser(Model model){

        Flux<User> all = userRepo.findAll();

        model.addAttribute("user", all);
        return "mainpage";
    }
```

I getting error in my Freemarker's template :

```
 ${user.content} оr  ${user}
```

reemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> user

Comment: I am almost certain that Freemarker doesn’t support reactive programming. You could call `iterator()` on the `Flux` to make it compatible. Alternatively thymeleaf does support reactive constructs - to the extent that it will render, e.g. tables client side and in a push based manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is, what do you need to call in Java to get the `content` of the `user`? When you write `user.content` in the template, with the default configuration FreeMarker will try things like `user.getContent()`, and `user.get("content")`. But this can be customized, with `Configuration.setObjectWrapper`. You could extend `DefaultObjectWrapper` so that it's aware of the `Flux` API.